# LyX 2.3.1 completes processing, but no pdf is visible in Acrobat

Tags: pdftex, lyx

I have created a few LyX files using 2.3.1 that are identical in their document settings, and yet, when I hit Ctrl + R, some files are processed to completion and throw up a pdf in Acrobat Reader DC, while others are processed to completion and do not appear in Acrobat. When a pdf file is not generated, I get the following messages at the end:

22:16:29.114: output file: C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.ljKjwYrYaULg/lyx_tmpbuf2/FileName.tex
22:16:29.115: 
22:16:29.161: pdfview "FileName.pdf"
22:16:29.163: Successful preview of format: PDF (pdflatex)

I can if I wish, to to File > Export > Export As ... and save a pdf file, but I would prefer that it come up automatically in Acrobat. Has anyone experienced this problem? If so, what is the solution?

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: you have masked your username thus guess FileName.pdf is not exact there are several possibilities based on filename with spaces punctuation utf-8 characters accents etc so watch what filenames you are having the issue with secondly acrobat notoriously locks you out of a second run since the first.pdf is still open  many TeX editors other than lyx run a close file before open is there a similar choice buried in your lyx configuration I don't see any acrobat related settings in Preferences Output general pdf command just those for sumatraPDF Okular Evince e.g. those that support reopening files

Comment: Actually found acrobat is treated as a special case and they use the pdfclose/open tools so if setting is auto its not using acrobat script but if its acrobat then it must be pdfview not auto 1) Open LyX/Tools/Preferences.../File Handling/File Formats 2) Change Format to "PDF (pdflatex)" 3) Check or Change "Viewer/Custom" to "pdfview"  this was an on/off problem for various viewer combinations as logged under https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9961

Comment: (Apologies I don't have high enought reputation to provide a comment) I had the same issue today and I fixed by choosing **PDF(pdflatex)** in the field "Format" and then choosing "**Custom**" as Viewer with the option **auto**. The latter option is crucial and circumvents the need to know the right .exe file name for the respective Viewer you are using. See a screenshot below. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGifS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGifS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bingo! KJO's answer has solved my problem. My username is trivial (only letters no spaces), so that wasn't it. The answer lay in Tools>Preferences>File Handling>File Formats.

The default format was BibTex (I have no idea why) so I changed it to PDF(pdflatex) and then chose AcroRd32 as my Viewer, hit Save and it now works like a charm. Interestingly, if I  choose pdfview as the Viewer, both the Save and Apply buttons are greyed out.

Thanks a mill!

Thomas Philips

Comment: Glad its sorted give yourself an accepted answer

Comment: Easy mistake to make, I almost made it, but the dropdown menu that originally was on bibtex *isn't* setting anything, it's just a way to choose which format you want to change the settings for. So the save/apply buttons were greyed out because before changing the viewer, you hadn't actually changed anything. Bibtex was selected by default because it's first in the alphabetical list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if Acrobat is your default pdf viewer; if not, make that. 
Reopen Lyx and under Tool bar, see Preferences then Path and then PATH Prefix.
Change the path of Ghostscript to Acrobat path. Apply and then Save

Comment: Good point - I do indeed have the folder containing AcroRd32.exe in my  path prefix. The weird thing is that it works for some files but not for others.